# error when using variable set as active workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a line of code that seems to generate an error no matter how it is written.
In this case:

```
Set Wbk = ActiveWorkbook

Wbk.Sht.Cells(Rw, 1) <> ""
```

I get error 438

If I change the last line to

```
Workbooks(WbName).Sht.Cells(Rw, 1) <> ""
```

where `WbName` is the active workbook name I get error 9.

If I scrap the workbook beginning and just `Sht` which is set to the worksheet it works.

Comment: what is your variable for `Sht`? Likely cause of your issues is that your variable `Sht` is `Set Sht = Workbooks("SomeWorkbook").Sheets("SomeWorksheet")`.  If that is true, then the correct syntax is simply `Sht.Cells(Rw, 1) <> 1`

Comment: You can't really chain variables like that.  If `Sht` is already parented to `Wbk` you don't need to include `Wbk` in the variable call.  Using `Wbk.Sht.Cells(...` is invalid, but just `Sht.Cells(...` would be valid.  To use just the `Wbk` variable would be `Wbk.Sheets("SheetName").Cells(...`

Comment: @tigeravatar I posted an answer, but if you wish to post your comment as answer, I'll delete mine :)

Answer (score 1):

[This link should tell you a lot of things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).
As for your question, let's elaborate what tigeravatar commented.

If you set your workbook like this:

```
Set Wbk = Activeworkbook
```

And your worksheet like this:

```
Set Sht = Activeworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

These 2 variables becomes independent of each other.
As what tigeravatar said, you cannot *chain* variables like that.
Or simply put, that violates the *Excel Object Hierarchy*.
There are times though that you need to use variables in reference to another object.
You can try this to access `Sht` through `Wbk`:

```
If Wbk.Sheets(Sht.Name).Cells(Rw, 1) <> "" Then
```

Or if you want to access the workbook using `Sht`:

```
Sht.Parent.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rw, 1) <> ""
```

Or something like this:

```
Sht.Parent.Parent.Worksbooks(Wbk.Name).Sheets(Sht.Name).Cells(Rw, 1) <> ""
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  I made a simple change and it works now.  This is in a called routine and Wbk is passed to this routine The line of code to set Wbk is : Set Wbk = ActiveWorkbook  Sht was declared as Worksheet and Set Sht = Sheets(1).  This generated the error.  I changed this to Y=1 and the line that got the error is now: If Wbk.Sheets(Y).Cells(Rw, 1) <> "" Then.  It works now.